# how copy a folder that have signs in it name in windows 7

Tags: windows-7

i bought a software disk. some folders have sign in those name. like $ and etc. i cant change folders name because they are related to eachother and are systemic.it was possible to copy files on windows xp. but when i want to copy on my main pc (win 7), nothing happening when i press paste.

Comment: What do you mean with "signs" and does the folder magically appear when you hit F5 (refresh)?

Comment: @LPChip no nothing appears. look name of folders are these: sƒ^îï╝1O.êç¢ and USBC╨s. i have edited my question

Comment: Can you copy the files/folder from the command prompt using the short windows name, or by autocompleting the name with tab?

Comment: @LPChip how? send answer please. simply please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Explorer might not be able to work with the folder, but the Command Prompt might still do it.

Depending on if you need administrative rights or not, either launch command prompt as administrator or normally.

Do note that a command prompt run as administrator won't have any network shares mounted by default (its a different user)

To start command prompt, press start, then type `cmd` and either hit enter or shift-enter depending on if you want to start it normally, or as administrator.

From the command prompt, use the following 2 commands to find the directory you want to copy:

`CD`: Change directory
`DIR`: Directory listing.

If the folder in question is on another drive, for example D:, simply type in the driveletter followed by : and press enter.

You can use tab to autocomplete file and foldernames.

For example, when in C:> typing cd prog<kbd>tab</kbd> will change it to: cd "Program Files". Pressing tab again without typing anything else will select the second possibility, thus cd "Program Files (x86)"

Once you are in the folder before the one you want to copy, you can type dir /x to find out the short name.

In order to copy the folder type `Copy <source> <destination>` You can use tab again to autocomplete the name.

If this fails, you can try copying using /n which means: use the generated short names.